# WebRTC: Track.onOpen() is called, but track is not open

Tags: c++, webrtc, libdatachannel

Using [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel), I establish a `PeerConnection` between two partners using some out-of-band signaling. I can create `DataChannel`s and send data between them successfully (with `peer_connection->createDataChannel()`).

But I am struggling to do the same with a video track. Here is what I do:

- I create a track from one partner:

```cpp
rtc::Description::Video media("myvideo", rtc::Description::Direction::RecvOnly);
media.addH264Codec(96);
media.setBitrate(3000);

auto track = peer_connection->addTrack(media);
peer_connection->setLocalDescription();
```

Note how I call `setLocalDescription()` after `addTrack`, so that libdatachannel will negotiate the track and I don't need to send an SDP out of band (at least that's my understanding).

- From the other partner, I check the `onTrack()` callback:

```cpp
peer_connection->onTrack([this](const std::shared_ptr<rtc::Track>& track) {
    track->onClosed([]() {
        std::cout << "onClosed" << std::endl;
    });
    track->onOpen([]() {
        std::cout << "onOpen" << std::endl;

        if (track->isOpen()) {
            std::cout << "track is open" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "track is not open" << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

What I observe is that `onTrack` is called, and the `track` has the `mid` I set from the sending side ("myvideo"). But right in the `onOpen()` callback, the call to `track->isOpen()` says that "track is **not** open".

If I try to use the track later (with e.g. `track->send()`), if fails with a SIGABRT:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Track is closed
Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)
```

So somehow it feels like my track was never properly open in the first place. Though I would expect `track->onOpen()` to be called... when the track is open.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was [a bug](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/pull/733) in `libdatachannel`.